# Can I play multi player Challenge Road in Mario Party?

Tags: super-mario-party

I unlocked/started the challenge road while in a party of one. I'm now trying to play this mode with more humans. Is this possible? If so, how? I have changed the party to include more human players but the games only ever let the first human play.

My kid unlocked challenge road so I didn't see any of the screens that may have explained if it is only single player. It seems like it would be fine to play with multiple people, especially since this is a party game. I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late response, and not one you might want, but - **no, you can't play challange road using multiple controllers with multiple people**.

Challenge road is intended to be a single player experience. The only way you can make it "multiplayer" is hot-seat game, where you and other people just pass the single joy-con around, but that's as much as multiplayer it gets.

Why Nintendo made it as such, I don't know. Especially because some of the minigames you play along the challenge road are Team Minigames, where the bot character you get to play with on the same team can literally ruin your otherwise good round of minigame.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had figured as much.. it's pretty weird, as you say, there are multiple players but we can't have multiple people controlling them 